# How to keep tablecells from inheritiing in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, uibutton, tablecell

I'm trying to generate cells in my table view, each with dynamically allowed buttons on the right-hand side; some with 2 buttons, some with 4 buttons. The problem is, though the table view loads as I'd like, upon scrolling around, the cells end up all having 4 buttons - even the ones that only had two before hand.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row][0]
cell.accessibilityLabel = self.items[indexPath.row][bigSort]

cell.selectionStyle = .None

for x in 0..<4
{
    let button = UIButton()
    let marginStart = w - tickWidthInCell * 4 - 9 + (tickWidthInCell + 2) * x
    let margin = CGFloat(marginStart)

    button.frame = CGRectMake(margin, CGFloat(cellHeightMargin), CGFloat(tickWidthInCell), CGFloat(tickHeightInCell))

    button.layer.borderColor = GRAY.CGColor

    if (self.items[indexPath.row][1] == "Special" && x % 2 != 0)
    {
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        //button.hidden = true

    }
    else
    {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cellButtonClicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex:0x222222)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
    cell.contentView.addSubview(button)

}


return cell
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a key part of the code. Give us your whole method for where you dequeue the cell.

Comment: Use something in scroll method of cells else the cells will be reused and it is bound to happen.

Comment: Remember cells get re used when you scroll.  you need to ensure your cell is good to be re used by overriding 'prepareForReuse' of you cell class and cleanup any state from an earlier initialisation there...

Comment: Added full dequeue. Can you give me an example how I might override 'prepareForReuse'? I'm new to this concept.

Comment: got it: I made a custom UITableViewCell class, and added:

    override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        self.contentView.subviews.forEach({

            if ($0.isKindOfClass(UIButton)) {
                $0.removeFromSuperview()
                print($0)
            }
        })
    }

This cleared all the buttons I had made before.

Answer (score 0):

It's because tableview reuses the cells you define. 
To get control over how the reusing should happen, in your custom `UITableViewCell` override `prepareForReuse`. And always reset them the state you want to be, like setting the cell to only have 2 buttons)

Or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can handle both cases to have either 2 buttons or 4.
(when you are specifying that you want 2 buttons make sure that you hide the other 2)